# How to determine is file a dll library using winapi

Tags: winapi, dll, c++-cli

I need to find all *.exe and *.dll files in selected directory (with subdirectories). For determining *.exe I use **GetBinaryType**, but I can't to determine that current file is dll.

The part of code

```
if (GetBinaryType(wName, &binaryType) || /*condition: if wName is DLL*/) {
    System::Diagnostics::Debug::WriteLine(fName);
}
```

Comment: So you are expecting or looking for files with invalid/incorrect extensions?

Comment: @crashmstr No, I just want to get names of all executable files and dynamic libraries.

Comment: So you can't just look at the file extension?

Comment: On Windows, generally executables have .exe or .com extensions, DLLs have .dll extension (unless someone is being "tricky" or something).

Comment: @Jonathan Potter, Yes, but it's intresting for me, is there another way?

Comment: File extension are irrelevant. While it is common to use .exe and .dll file extensions, there is no enforced requirement to do so (e.g. screen saver files/.scr, ActiveX controls/.ocx). If you want a robust solution you will have to check for a valid PE(+) header. See [Peering Inside the PE: A Tour of the Win32 Portable Executable File Format](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms809762.aspx) to get basic information about PE(+) files.

Comment: @IInspectable: I think the OP wants to be able to differentiate between DLLs and EXEs. Do you have a reference for doing that using the PE format?

Comment: @Jonathan: There is no difference between EXE files and DLL files. They are both PE files. The only difference is conventional, i.e. how the OS loader deals with .exe files. If you need to differentiate between EXEs and DLLs, there is absolutely nothing you can do, besides checking file extensions. Which are meaningless, as has been established before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just read [IMAGE_FILE_HEADER](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms680313%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) record of file. If Characteristics field contain IMAGE_FILE_DLL flag - you have dll.

Comment: The procedure to get to the PE characteristics is outlined [here](http://www.delphidabbler.com/articles?article=8). Note that some tools will produce DLLs that do not have this flag set. While solid in theory, this is not a robust solution in practice. It's still the best you can hope for.